# Data table not displaying

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to do a mern application with react and I am trying to display data on a table but it is not showing up

[image]

So this is my react page and I get that console error in the console I will display my App.js getstudent.js and lastly my displaytable.js

App. js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import GetStudents from './getstudents';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
  <div>
  <GetStudents/>

  </div>
)
}
}

export default App;
```

getstudent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import TableRow from './displaytable';
class GetStudents extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      student:[]
    }
  }

 componentDidMount() {
  axios.get( "http://localhost:3200/students")
   .then((myJson) => {
     this.setState({student:myJson.data});
   })
   .catch(error => console.error(error)); //If error occurs you will get here

}

tableRow () {
  return this.state.student.map(function(err, e) {
    return <TableRow obj={err} key={e} />
  });
}
render() {
  return(
   <div>
      <h1 align= "center">Student Attendance</h1>
      <table className = 'table-table-stripped' style={{margin:25}}>
       <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Student Id</th>
            <th>Role Num</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Marks</th>

          </tr>

       </thead>
      <tbody>
         {this.tableRow}
      </tbody>

      </table>


   </div>
  )
}

}
export default GetStudents;
```

displaytable.js which is supposed to display the data

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class TableRow extends  React.Component {
render() {
  return(
   <tr>
      <td>{this.props.obj._id}</td>
      <td>{this.props.obj.role_num} </td>
       <td>{this.props.obj.first_name}</td>
      <td>{this.props.obj.last_name}</td>
      <td><button className = 'btn-btn-danger'>Update</button> </td>
      <td><button className = 'btn-btn-danger'> Remove</button></td>
   </tr>

  )
}
}
export default TableRow;
```

Comment: @CatarinaFerreira what do you mean by that

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `tableRow()` function in return statement:

```
      <tbody>
         {this.tableRow()}
      </tbody>
```

*edit
You have to also change your `tableRow` function. It should return one element or an array of elements, so:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
...
tableRow () {
  return (
  <Fragment>
  {
     this.state.student.map(function(err, e) {
       return <TableRow obj={err} key={e} />
     })
  }
  </Fragment>
}
```

Comment: I called it I still get the same error and my page is blank

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one another component which you used for table body and inside that component do the same which you are doing in table row function and that component you call instead of function. Following is your new component

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class TableBody extends  React.Component { 
render() {
return(

    {this.state.student.map(function(err, e) {
      return <TableRow obj={err} key={e} />
    });}
  )}
  }
  export default TableBody;
```

Then call this new component under tbody like following

```
<tbody>
   <TableBody>
</tbody>
```

Comment: so do I create another file

Comment: I also get unexpected keyword this